# How to mock bytes method (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, testing, mocking, byte

I'm working on a networking application and I'm writing tests for it. I need to mock the bytes representation of a `MagicMock` object I created and I'm having trouble with it; you'll see the problem below:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock

my_mock = MagicMock()
my_mock.__bytes__ = Mock(return_value=b"\1\2\3")

print(bytes(my_mock))  # expected b'\x01\x02\x03' but prints b'\x00'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you testing? I'm not sure it makes sense to use a mock as a test double if this is its only behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a class `FilesystemCache` which holds information about a directory and it's (recursive) contents such as checksum, last modification time etc. This class has a `__bytes__` method for providing a `bytes` representation of it. I'm trying to mock this class and a few of its behavior.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am grateful that you provided a minimal example of the thing you want to achieve, without adding stuff that will only be relevant in your actual implementation.

Unfortunately, I don't have an answer at this time.